# Flutter flutter_facebook_login plugin issues (v 3.0.0)

Tags: flutter

I am having issues running facebook login on my flutter app. I am using

`flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0`

And when I run the app, I get this

`Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro in debug mode...
Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

```
Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `.symlinks/flutter/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_analytics` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_analytics/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `flutter_facebook_login` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_facebook_login/ios`

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
  CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_3_5.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.13.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/1.0.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
  ... 
  ...
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.13.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "flutter_facebook_login":
  In Podfile:
    flutter_facebook_login (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_facebook_login/ios`)

Specs satisfying the `flutter_facebook_login (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_facebook_login/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:328:in `raise_error_unless_state'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:310:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `tap'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `unwind_for_conflict'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:684:in `attempt_to_activate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in `process_topmost_state'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:986:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:984:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:410:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:234:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:233:in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:156:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

 Error output from CocoaPods:
 ↳

[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `8.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
```

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro.`

---

And when I `pod update`,  I get this -

`pod update                                                                                                                          1 ↵  26  15:58:28
Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "flutter_facebook_login":
  In Podfile:
    flutter_facebook_login (from`.symlinks/plugins/flutter_facebook_login/ios`)

Specs satisfying the `flutter_facebook_login (from`.symlinks/plugins/flutter_facebook_login/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `8.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

---

Not sure whats going on. Any idea how I can fix this ? Thank you !
`

Answer (score 4):

Try to follow this step:

1. Run command `flutter clean`.
2. Run command `pod cache clean --all`
3. Remove these files and folders `Podfile.lock`, `.symlinks`, `Pods`
4. Open Podfile, On the top of the file uncomment this line and config
   minimum iOS platform to 9.0.

> Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
```

5. Run command `pod repo update`
6. Try to run `pod install` again

Credits **[edwardmelody](https://github.com/roughike/flutter_facebook_login/issues/185#issuecomment-536812802)**

Comment: I did all of that, still throws -  `*** First throw call stack:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011015d02e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010ffd5b20 objc_exception_throw + 48
 2   FBSDKCoreKit                        0x000000010af8100f +[FBSDKInternalUtility validateAppID] + 175
 3   FBSDKCoreKit                        0x000000010af811b1 +[FBSDKInternalUtility 
 7   FBSDKLoginKit               <…>
Lost connection to device.

Comment: still failing for me

Comment: Sorry @sharath I did not see your comment, did you solve the issues?. **Dani**, what error are your getting?

Answer (score 3):

i did what @Haniel Baez said but i was still getting the same message , in my case i sorted the issue by checking under that path /My_Project/ios/Pods/Local Podspecs/flutter_facebook_auth.podspec.json , inside that json file you'll find the minimum iOS version required for that fbpackage to work in my case it was iOS 10 as shown on the screenshot below [image]

and then you go to your POD File and you uncomment the first line which is by default  "platform :ios, '9.0' ", you change it to  "platform :ios, '10.0'" as seen on the picture [image]

and you start debugging , as you're debugging you should see new directories getting downloaded to your project under the name FB****** under the PODS Directory as seen on the scrennshots added, and your app should compile and work normally .

Comment: this is the correct way to solve it!